# eth0 for PXE and local only, eth1 for internet access and ssh

Tags: linux, iptables, route

I am using CentOS 7 (yes I know it's old). I have eth0 which is default for PXE booting and local network access. I also have eth1 which I like to use for internet access and remote access via ssh port 22 or 23 to eth1. How can I achieve this? I search and try different configuration but can't get it to work. I like to learn so pls explain your answer. Thanks.

```
# ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0
default via 10.10.12.1 dev eth1 proto static metric 102
10.10.0.0/16 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.12.155 metric 102
192.168.0.0/18 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.58

# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         10.10.12.1     0.0.0.0         UG    102    0        0 eth1
10.10.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     102    0        0 eth1
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.192.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Answer (score 1):

PXE implies you probably get the network settings for `eth0` using DHCP.

What kind of settings do you use for `eth1` (static or DHCP)?

Are you using NetworkManager or classic `ifcfg-<interface>` files to configure your network interfaces? (What is the output of `nmcli c show`?)

You would have to configure the DHCP client for `eth0` to ignore any default gateway setting provided by the DHCP server, or to assign a higher-than-normal (and higher than 102) metric value for it. Then you would have to ensure that `eth1`'s default gateway is valid.

With NetworkManager, you could achieve this by setting the `ipv4.never-default` attribute to TRUE for the connection of `eth0`. For example:

```
nmcli connection modify <connection_name_of_eth0> ipv4.never-default TRUE
```

Of course you should replace the `<connection_name_of_eth0>` with the actual connection name you're using.

Comment: eth0 is using DHCP. eth1 is set Static. I use NetworkManager to configure.

Comment: it works. Thanks.